# Reference Implementation for MVVM with Hierarchical Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I read a couple of MVVM Tutorials ([1](http://www.infoq.com/articles/View-Model-Definition),[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx),[3](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-implement-MVVM-71a65441),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303804/mvvm-for-collections)) but I can't find a proper answer to my problem.

My model is a hierarchical tree like this:

```
public class MyModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<MyModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to display this in a TreeView like this (each entry if from the type MyModel):

```
Root
|-SubElement
|-SubElement2
|  |-SubSubElement1
|-SubElement3
```

Now my questions:

- How would the corresponding View-Model look like? Is there a reference implementation for Collections?
- Should the Model or the View-Model or both implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` or should the List of Children be of the Type `ObservableCollection<MyModel>`? If so, when to call `OnPropertyChanged()`?

Now for the displaying:

I would like to display the Name of the object in the TreeView, but when selecting the element, I want to be notified of that event (and get the corresponding element). The ViewModel must somehow support this. Something like holding a list (say `MyModelList`) to which I can bind in XAML, like:

```
<TreeView ...
   ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyModelList, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"

... >
```

and where I can use `InputBindings` or `EventTriggers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Hierarchical data template for showing tree structure within TreeView

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
                                  DataType="{x:Type local:MyModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid .Resources>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelList}"/>
</Grid>
```

Go through this MSDN Blog to get a better understanding - [TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate, Step-by-Step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the tutorial you provided only shows the use of the Template for three layers, whereas in my case I possibly have an infinite number of sub-layers, since each object of `MyModel` can have many `MyModel`-children.

Comment: That example is for your understanding of hierarchichal template. The sample code above should be able to solve your problem. The hierarchical template will apply for every element and it will create child elements wherever the list is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

> `How would the corresponding View-Model look like?`

In this situation will be `Model` and the collection, which will be in the `ViewModel`.

---

> `Should the Model or the View-Model or both implement INotifyPropertyChanged`

I advise you to use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because all changes for Collection will automatically (add, remove, etc) appear in it. Properties that will be in `Model` must implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. I personally do it on the side of the `Model`, but there are opponents of this idea, so where to implement it - your personal desire.

Example of this idea:

**`Model`**

```
public class MyModel : NotificationObject // he implement INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   ...
}
```

**`ViewModel`**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyObjects 
{
    get;
    set;
}

// in Constructor of ViewModel
MyLogObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
```

---

> `When selecting the element, I want to be notified of that event`

In WPF and Silverlight `TreeView.SelectedItem` is a readonly property. In this case you can see [`this`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18188.wpf-treeview-selecteditem-twoway-mvvm-plus-expand-to-selected-and-close-all-others.aspx) example:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot"> 
    <StackPanel.Resources> 
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" > 
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" /> 
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate> 

        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" 
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" /> 
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
    </StackPanel.Resources> 

    <sdk:TreeView x:Name="myTreeView"
                  Width="400"  
                  Height="300" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding HierarchicalAreas}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}"
                  local:Attached.TreeViewSelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArea, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

*Prefix `sdk:` needed for Silverlight*

For notified event you can create an `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event handler for `ViewModel` in constructor, to know that the *`SelectedItem`* changed:

```
public MyViewModel() 
{
    MyModel = new MyModel();        
    MyModel.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyModel_PropertyChanged);
}

private void MyModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("SelectedItem")) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SelectedItem changed");
    }            
}
```